# this._nativeModule.addListener is undefined

Tags: reactjs, react-native, undefined

RN Version : 0.49.3

I m trying to build a project on iOS simulator with a Mac. But I got the red screen, with this message :

```
this._nativeModule.addListener is not a function ...
this._nativeModule.addListener is undefined
```

I tried everything and also rm -rf node_modules then nom install, nothings worked...I checked if the listening port was ok...

The build is success, but then I got the red screen.

Thank s for your help

Comment: have you tried running `rnpm link`? This is caused by the KeyboardObserver according to an issue filed in the project repo.

Comment: Yeah I did it, everything works well, I just got this error at the end : It seems something went wrong while linking. Error: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined 
Please file an issue here: https://github.com/rnpm/rnpm/issues 
(node:39363) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined......But my guess was that it wasn't the main cause of the red screen. Could it be ?

Comment: seems quite possible, yeah. Either way, you'll have to fix it at some point.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, it was a librairie which wasn't well installed...

Comment: an iOS library, react-native-intercom, which was configured with Carthage, just went to iOS and run `carthage update` to install it. Be sure that you installed all your dependencies, and also the Carthage and Pods one...